# dplyr:summarize unknown number of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to be able to `summarize` a grouped data frame where I don't always know what variables will be present, but I do know how I want to summarize each variable if it is present.

Let's say I have a dataframe as such:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep('a', 5), rep('b', 8), rep('c', 4)),
                 var1 = round(runif(17) * 10, 3),
                 var2 = sample(c(1:4), 17, replace = TRUE),
                 var4 = sample(1:1000, 17))
> df

   id  var1 var2 var4
1   a 5.930    4  360
2   a 7.265    2  713
3   a 3.704    3  117
4   a 5.149    2  782
5   a 3.777    2  640
6   b 4.183    2  802
7   b 0.107    2  638
8   b 5.323    4  327
9   b 4.322    2  631
10  b 0.937    3  921
11  b 5.558    2  570
12  b 5.902    4  363
13  b 0.671    3  432
14  c 0.475    1  845
15  c 1.562    3  620
16  c 4.464    2  997
17  c 1.714    2  714
```

Notice var3 is missing.  Sometimes it is there, sometimes it is not. It's always the same type when it is present.  I would like to be able to neatly handle both cases.

Let's say that, summarizing by `id`, I want to get the mean of `var1`, the median of `var2`, the median of `var3` (when present) and the max of `var4`.  If all variables were present I could set it up like this:

```
library('dplyr')
set.seed(111)
result <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(var1 = mean(var1),
            var2 = median(var2),
            var3 = median(var3),
            var4 = max(var4))
```

However, since `var3` is not there, I get an error: `Error in median(var3) : object 'var3' not found`.

Intuitively, I would try something like:

```
result <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(if('var1' %in% names(df)) var1 = mean(var1) else NULL,
            if('var2' %in% names(df)) var2 = median(var2) else NULL,
            if('var3' %in% names(df)) var3 = median(var3) else NULL,
            if('var4' %in% names(df)) var4 = max(var4) else NULL)
```

But obviously that doesn't work, or maybe my intuition is a little off.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might accomplish this cleanly using dplyr?  As you might guess, `df` in reality is a large data frame with many columns and `var3` is one of any number columns that could be missing.

Comment: If it were me, I would probably modify the data frame up front to include the maximal set of columns I could possibly have, and some of the columns might just be all NA.

Comment: I think you could hack something together with some conditional `eval` and `parse`, but joran's proposal seems much more the way to go.

Comment: My first approach would probably be to melt the data, then get all stats you might need for each group using dplyr and then recast, you could then check to see what columns you actually have before processing further

Comment: @joran, I like your solution.  I ended up going with @beginneR's solution--maybe a bit of extra typing with all the `ifelse`s, but I only need to list all the variables one time.  It ended up looking a little neater and will be easier to maintain (I can add/subtract a column's summarization in just one place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exactly the solution, but perhaps a workaround, if you don't want to create all possible columns upfront as suggested by @joran. It will first create all columns you specify but some of them will be only `NA`. Afterwards you could delete the columns using apply. Note however, that the `names(dd)`, when used inside the `dplyr` chain, only recognizes the column names that were in the input data.frame, not those created in the same operation.

```
dd <- dd %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(var1 = ifelse("var1" %in% names(dd), mean(var1), NA),
            var2 = ifelse("var2" %in% names(dd), max(var2), NA))  

dd <- dd[,apply(dd, 2, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), FALSE, TRUE))]
```

Another potential workaround could be using the `summarise_each` function but I think that would depend on whether you want, for example, the mean, median and max of all columns or not.

Comment: I didn't know about summarise_each -- thanks for the tip!  I'm sure that will come in handy at some point.  I ended up using your suggestion, but slightly modifying it so I didn't have to use apply.  I simply added: `dfcols <- names(df)` before the dplyr manipulations, and `result <- df[dfcols]` after.

Comment: That's a nice simplification I didn't think of.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in several steps:

1. convert from wide to long using `melt`
2. summarise using `dplyr`
3. convert from long to wide using `dcast`

For example:

```
tmp <- melt(df, id.vars="id")

tmp <- tmp %>%
  group_by(id, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), median = median(value), max = max(value))

tmp <- melt(tmp, id.vars=c("id", "variable"), variable.name="stat")

tmp <- dcast(tmp, id ~ stat + variable)
```

I had to add an extra step because you want mean, median, and max for the different variables.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion--this seems like another decent approach. I accepted @beginneR's solution because it didn't involve loading another package.